# Django objects.filter is not updating field but objects.get is

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a Django model :

```
class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
   marks = models.FloatField(null=True)
   graded = models.IntegerField()
```

Now in command line I do:

```
>>> qa = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qa[0].graded 
0
>>> qa[0].graded = 1
>>> qa[0].save()
>>> qa = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qa.graded
0
```

The `graded` field is not updated.

But when I do:

```
>>> qa = QuestionAnswer.objects.get(pk=12345)
>>> qa.graded 
0
>>> qa.graded = 1
>>> qa.save()
>>> qa = QuestionAnswer.objects.get(pk=12345)
>>> qa.graded
1
```

Why does `objects.filter` not updating the field but `objects.get` works?

Comment: In the last statement you do `qa.graded` instead of `qa[0].graded`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> qs = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qa = qs[0]
>>> qa.graded
0
>>> qa.graded = 1
>>> qa.save()
>>> qa = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qa[0].graded
This should be 1
```

By using `qa[0]`, you're not actually modifying and saving the same object (even though they represent the same SQL data).

This is due to the fact that querysets are lazy: they only execute the sql query when you actually try to use the data that the queryset would return. The way slices work with querysets, the query is executed but the result will not be cached. This means that whenever you use `qa[0]`, a new query is executed, and that data is saved in a newly created model instance. What you are effectively doing is this:

```
>>> qs = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qa1 = qs.get()
>>> qa1.graded
0
>>> qa2 = qs.get()
>>> qa2.graded = 1
>>> qa3 = qs.get()
>>> qa3.save()
```

It should be obvious that `qa1`, `qa2` and `qa3` are different instances of your model: while they have the same attribute values (as the represent the same database data), they are actually saved in different places in memory and are completely separate from each other. Changing the `graded` attribute on `qa2` will not in any way affect `qa3`, so when `qa3` is saved, the changes to `qa2` won't be reflected in the changes in the database.

However, if you were to evaluate the entire queryset before slicing, all results would be cached, and the following *would* work:

```
>>> qs = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qs[0] is qs[0]
False # These are not the same objects in memory...
>>> bool(qs) # This forces evaluation of the entire queryset
True
>>> qs[0] is qs[0]
True # ... but these are!
>>> qs[0].graded
0
>>> qs[0].graded = 1
>>> qs[0].save()
>>> qs = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345)
>>> qs[0].graded
1
```

Comment: >>> type qa[0]  gives 
<class 'toolbox.models.QuestionAnswer'>

Then why qa[0] isn't the QuestionAnswer object?

Comment: Not sure what you think that proves. Do `qa[0] is qa[0]` to see that you get a new object every time you slice.

Answer (score 3):

Try out this when you use filter in ORM query to update

```
QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(pk=12345).update(graded=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` returns a `QuerySet` (even though it looks like a list). In django, [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) which means they are evaluated only when needed.

`get` returns the actual object which is not "lazy"; which is why your changes seem to be effected immediately.

To solve your problem, you need to evaluate the queryset. You can do this by iterating over it (in a for loop), or converting it to a list.

However, since you are filtering by the primary key, you should be using `get` anyway; but keep in mind `get` will raise exception when the key is not found, or when multiple objects are returned:

```
try:
   foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=-1)
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
   print('There is no foo with pk 1')
except Foo.MultipleObjectsReturned:
   print('Oh no! Multiple foos with key 1!')

print('I am the foo with key 1: {}'.format(foo))
```